# Constructive or closed-form expression for order $p$ element $x\in\left({\Bbb Z}\over{q\Bbb Z}\right)^\times$ for $p$, $q$ primes, $p\mid q-1$

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields, closed-form, multiplicative-order

I was looking for groups with order $pq$ for primes $p$ and $q$, and found that it wasn't too hard to classify all of them up to isomorphism. In particular, if $p=q$ then we have $C_{p^2}$ or $C_p\times C_p$. Otherwise, w.l.o.g. $p<q$. Then if $p\not\mid q-1$ we have only $C_{pq}$, and finally if $p\mid q-1$ we have $C_{pq}$, and a single non-abelian case, $C_p \ltimes C_q$.

The non-abelian case can be presented as $\langle g,h\vert g^q=h^p=1, gh=hg^x\rangle$ where $x$ is some integer such that $x\not\equiv1\pmod q$ (else the group is abelian) and $x^p\equiv1\pmod q$ (otherwise $p\not\mid\text{ord}(x)=n$, so $h^n$ generates $\langle h\rangle$, but $gh^n=h^ng^{x^n}=h^ng$, contradicting that the group is not abelian).

By the multiplicative group modulo prime $q$ being cyclic, it is clear that there are exactly $p-1$ distinct choices of $x$ up to congruence modulo $q$ provided that $p\mid q-1$; they are the order $p$ elements of $\left({\Bbb Z}\over{q\Bbb Z}\right)^\times$, which form a cyclic subgroup. Moreover, there are obvious automorphisms of the non-abelian group which show that all such choices of $x$ give the same group up to isomorphism.

So I was then wondering if there was a way to construct a particular such integer $x$ given $p$ and $q$ (perhaps using some standard operations for a closed-form expression) which would give a "nice" presentation of the group, i.e. without needing the extra information that $x$ satisfies some congruences which aren't constructive and don't make it very clear that this is always the same group up to isomorphism.

I can only find a solution to this in the obvious special cases. Firstly, the trivial case $p=2$ (and hence $q$ an odd prime), where the only such $x$ is $x\equiv-1\pmod q$. But then we simply have the dihedral group $D_{2q}$ anyway, so this case isn't very interesting or helpful. Secondly, very special cases where we are given that $q$ is a prime factor of ${x^p-1}\over{x-1}$ (for example, $x=2$, $p$ is a mersenne prime exponent, and $q$ is the mersenne prime itself) in which case that particular $x$ is given, so this is also not very helpful for the general case.

For any other case (even simply $p=3$) the next best thing I could think of was just saying, for example, that $x$ is the least positive integer satisfying the condition, which you might write as $\min{\{n\in\Bbb N:n^p\equiv1\pmod q,1<n<q\}}$, but this still doesn't feel very useful or constructive, and certainly would look quite strange as the exponent of $g$.

Comment: The somewhat obvious but  non-deterministic and non-glamorous way of locating such an $x$ is the following. Let $N=(q-1)/p$. Pick a random integer $a$ in the range $1<a<q-1$ (more often than not $a=2$ will be random enough). Calculate the remainder $x$ of $a^N$ modulo $q$ by some efficient method such as [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). If you are lucky, then $x\neq1$, and you are done. If you are unlucky, then you need to pick another random $a$, and try again.

Comment: (cont'd) The odds of success are $p-1:1$ in your favor with each random $a$, so soon enough you will get what you want. The *non-deterministic* part is about not knowing in advance which $a$ will work. IIRC there are results giving a worst case upper bound. Those may rely on things like generalized Riemann hypothesis, but you don't really need to worry about that. Anyway, Little Fermat guarantees that $x^p\equiv a^{q-1}\mod q$ for every choice of $a$.

Comment: I realize that this may be a bit disappointing in the sense that you may not want to call this *closed form*. I would say that those are possible only when $N$ is rather small. Like with pairs of Sophie Germain primes $q=2p+1$ with $N=2$, when $x=4$ will work :-)

Comment: Compare this with the following. It is only known that [the least quadratic non-residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Least_quadratic_non-residue) modulo $q$ is at most $\ll (\log q)^2$. And that's assuming GRH. This is equivalent to finding the least $x$ such that its order is not a factor of $(q-1)/2$. Bringing this up to highlight the difficulty of obtaining certain types of closed form answers here, and to make you appreciate the non-deterministic answers at least a little.

Comment: A special case worth mentioning may be $p=3$. Finding a third root of unity is always equivalent to finding a square root of $-3$. There are methods for locating modular square roots. Search for those, if this is of interest.

Comment: I also suspect that this has been explained on our site already. Which is the reason why I respond in comments.